# Get Content-Type from cURL

Tags: php, curl, header

This works great to get the header

```
 $imageurl = "http://p.twimg.com/AW2-vIUCAAE_1FN.png";

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image_url);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

  $content = curl_exec ($ch);

  curl_close ($ch);

  print_r($content);
```

returning

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
X-peep-host: den2twapi014
Last-Modified: Mon, 15 Aug 2011 03:41:50 GMT
ETag: "7283847-dbb8-4aa830b1dabf0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 56248
Cache-Control: public, max-age=21600
Expires: Wed, 28 Mar 2012 15:53:57 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
X-CDN: AKAM
Date: Wed, 28 Mar 2012 09:53:57 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

what is the best way to echo out the `Content-Type:` ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<?php
$image_url = "http://p.twimg.com/AW2-vIUCAAE_1FN.png";

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image_url);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

  $content = curl_exec ($ch);
  $contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    echo $contentType;
    echo "<br/>";
  curl_close ($ch);
    echo "<pre>";
  print_r($content);
  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a list of valid Content Types, mainly for images, but would be good to know them all.

Answer (score 5):

Before you call `curl_close()`, call [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php):

```
$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
echo $contentType;
```

Alternatively, if you want a parsed array of the head, here is a quick and dirty solution (WARNING: this does nothing to validate that the supplied string actually is an HTTP response, use with caution):

```
<?php

  function parse_http_head ($str) {

    $result = array();

    // Split into lines
    $lines = explode("\r\n", $str);

    // Handle response line
    $line = explode(' ', array_shift($lines), 3);
    $version = explode('/', $line[0]);
    $result['version'] = (float) $version[1];
    $result['code'] = (int) $line[1];
    $result['text'] = $line[2];

    // Parse headers
    $result['headers'] = array();
    while ($line = trim(array_shift($lines))) {
      list($name, $val) = explode(':', $line, 2);
      $name = strtolower(trim($name)); // Header names are case-insensitive, so convert them all to lower case so we can easily use isset()
      if (isset($result['headers'][$name])) { // Some headers (like Set-Cookie:) may appear more than once, so convert them to an array if necessary
        $result['headers'][$name] = (array) $result['headers'][$name];
        $result['headers'][$name][] = trim($val);
      } else {
        $result['headers'][$name] = trim($val);
      }
    }

    return $result;

  }

  // $content comes from your code above
  $parsed = parse_http_head($content);
  print_r($parsed);

/*
 Output:

Array
(
    [version] => 1.1
    [code] => 200
    [text] => OK
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [server] => nginx
            [x-peep-host] => den2twapi014
            [last-modified] => Mon, 15 Aug 2011 03:41:50 GMT
            [etag] => "7283847-dbb8-4aa830b1dabf0"
            [accept-ranges] => bytes
            [content-length] => 56248
            [cache-control] => public, max-age=21600
            [expires] => Wed, 28 Mar 2012 15:53:57 GMT
            [content-type] => image/png
            [x-cdn] => AKAM
            [date] => Wed, 28 Mar 2012 09:53:57 GMT
            [connection] => keep-alive
        )

)

*/
```